# Collapse of Hirzebruch Spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

This question is actually about reading Adams' *Stable Homotopy and Generalised Cohomology*; in Part II chapter 2, there are two numbered lemmata (Lemma 2.5 contravariant, 2.14 covariant) to the effect that

> The Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequences $H_p(\mathbb{CP}^\infty,E_q(*))\Rightarrow E_{p+q}(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)$ and $H_p(\mathbb{CP}^\infty\times \mathbb{CP}^\infty,E_q(*))\Rightarrow E_{p+q}(\mathbb{CP}^\infty\times \mathbb{CP}^\infty)$ collapse at page 2.

Now, read in context, Adams has already mentioned that there are three spectra he's interested in: $H,KU,MU$ (where the AH-SS indeed collapses for sparsity reasons); but there is no mention of this in the statements of either lemma, nor in the (*very* terse) arguments given.

**Question**  Can someone confirm whether $E\in \{ H, KU , MU \}$ is in fact what Adams meant?

Comment: Jesse, please give numbers of numbered statements and a more precise reference.  A first glance shows me nothing that matches your description.

Comment: OK, so what's going on here is I've confused myself about which Adams book I was looking at; this in part due to someone-else having confused me about which Adams book I was looking at, but... adjusting in a couple of minutes... though I suspect you particularly could still guess what Adams meant better than I. (but guessing is not what we're about, either...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact reference, but I guess $H$, $KU$ and $MU$ are probably *in particular* what is meant.

In general, the Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence collapses for *complex oriented* multiplicative cohomology theories (cf. e.g. Proposition 7 in [Lecture 4](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252xnotes/Lecture4.pdf) of Lurie's notes on chromatic homotopy theory).

**Edit**: Now that we have a more precise reference, I found that that in the beginning of that chapter it reads:

> We will study [ring] spectra $Ε$ which are provided with "orientations",
>   in the following sense (which owes much to a seminar by A. Dold).
>   There is given an element $x \in \tilde{E}^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)$ such that
>   $\tilde{E}^*(\mathbb{C}P^1)$ is a free module over $\pi_*(E)$ on the generator $i^*x$, where $i \colon \mathbb{C}P^1 \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is the inclusion map.

So it looks like what Adams actually means is also a general complex oriented cohomology theory (resp. complex oriented spectrum).

Comment: You may want to emphasize that the condition on the orientability of $E$ is crucial here.  For example, if $E=S$, the SS doesn't collapse at $E_2$.